# How do I add a customised popup for a Java RCP application which launches only when it has java 7 or higher versions(32-bit)?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

Currently, I have an application which is built using Java RCP(Eclipse Mars). It can launch only if the system has JAVA 7 Or any other higher version(32-bit only). When trying to launch using JAVA 6 it throws up a popup.(See attached [popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13PEw.png)).[Some Users might still have Java 6 in their system]. I would like to add my own customised dialog instead of this. How can this be achieved? Any thoughts? I'm attaching the error log here for your reference.[Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXQtd.png)
[image: 64 bit popup]

Answer (score 0):

you need to get the information at runtime and launch your modal popup

this to get the version 1.6, 1.7 1.8 etc

```
String v = System.getProperty("java.specification.version");
```

this for getting the arch. (32 or 64)

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model"));
```

this method to display your pop up modal dialog

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(....);
```

now take this example as an orienatation point and build latter your own conditions:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String v = System.getProperty("java.specification.version");
    Double d = new Double(v);
    if (Double.compare(d, 1.6) == 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ups!! this java version is not supported!", "Opala", 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But it didn't solve my problem yet. I'm unable to get the required version at run time. The crash happens much earlier, probably at the workbench level. Unable to figure it out. If you have any further suggestions, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

If you add the following line to your `<executable>.ini` below the line `-vmargs`:

```
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
```

then a dialog with a message that can not be customized (because the message is hard-coded in the Eclipse Equinox framework: see [source code](https://git.eclipse.org/c/equinox/rt.equinox.framework.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher/src/org/eclipse/equinox/launcher/Main.java#n682)) similar to the following will pops up instead:

[image]

Alternatively, you can bundle your Eclipse RCP application with a JRE.

Comment: This works fine, but it still doesn't answer my question. I would still be needing a customised popup as users could still try to launch the application with a 64-bit java version. In that case, there would be no popup. It would be nice to have a popup that says "my application supports only 32-bit JVM (7 or higher)" in that popup.

Comment: I have tried to add -d32 above the -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7 and it works!. It launches only if there is 32 bit Java installed(1.7 or higher).

Comment: `-d32` is an Oracle specific Java parameter. Which dialog do you see with `-d32` and only a 64 bit JVM of version 7 installed? Unfortunately, the dialog message can not be customized (see my edits).

Comment: I agree with you, I will still not be able to customise the popup.(Thought this might be a workaround).I see this dialog(64 bit popup) when i have a 64 bit JVM of version 8 installed. Strangely, i don't see this popup when I have version 7 installed.

Comment: Without the addition of -d32 in the ini, when i try to launch my application with 64 bit JVM(version 8)...I couldn't(nothing happened). I tried using other 64 bit JVM's to see what happens(version 6 & 7). It gave a dialog saying "A Java Runtime Environment(JRE) or Java Development Kit(JDK) must be available to run your application. No Java Virtual Machine was found......". I assumed this case would be taken care by the introduction of -d32 in the ini. However, the error dialog is seen only in the case of JVM 8 ,64-bit . In the case of JVM's 6 & 7 I still get the same dialog.

Comment: There is also the parameter [-Dosgi.arch=x86](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html) which also does not solve your problem. Could you ship your application with a JVM (in the subfolder _jre_ of your Eclipse RCP application)?

Comment: Previously we were doing the same thing, but due to some requirements we had to decouple the JVM from the application. That is when this issue has started to appear.